# Discrepancy in calculation using modulo operator

Tags: r

I am trying to find cube root of a set of numbers using following

```
x^(1/3) %% 1 ==0
```

but I am not getting the correct value. When I tried to see what is happening in the console found the following behavior :

```
> 4 %% 1
[1] 0
> 64^(1/3) %% 1
[1] 1
```

Why is this giving different results? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you look at `(64^(1/3) %% 1) == 1`, you'll see that it is not precisely `1`. This is likely a case of floating-point problems, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal.

Comment: Try `as.integer(64^(1/3) ) %% 1`

Comment: Also note that while `4^3 == 64` is true, unfortunately `64^(1/3) == 4` is false. While counter-intuitive, this is consistent with the unreliability of floating-point *equality* in any digital computer system that does not implement "arbitrary precision" (i.e., most computer systems/languages).

Comment: If you need integer calculations and integer equality, then the only way you can guarantee rationale (intuitive) equality is to make things actual `integer`s and ensure that R doesn't coerce back to `numeric` (which it can do, silently). Lacking that, floating-point equality works great until it doesn't, without warning or error. The usual recommendation of "tolerance" (e.g., `abs(x - 1) < 1e-8` to approximate `== 1`) doesn't work well with `%%`, so you're likely stuck with akrun's recommendation to use `as.integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a mathematical perspective, a workaround is to factorize `x` first (`pracma::factors` is used in the following example), e.g.,

```
nRoot <- function(x, n = 3) {
  u <- pracma::factors(x)
  prod(unique(u)**(table(u) / n))
}
```

then you will see

```
> nRoot(64) %% 1
[1] 0

> nRoot(216) %% 1
[1] 0
```

while

```
> 64^(1/3) %% 1
[1] 1

> 216^(1/3) %% 1
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If we convert to integer, it would work

```
as.integer(64^(1/3) ) %% 1
```